# How to speed up group by

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to speed up the following query, which currently takes 14 seconds:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS employee_count, e.jurisdiction_id, e.year
FROM
  employee_employee e
GROUP BY
  e.jurisdiction_id, e.year
ORDER BY
  employee_count ASC;
```

I add an index by running:

```
CREATE INDEX ON employee_employee (jurisdiction_id, year);
```

But that did very little to improve the timing because the GROUP BY is taking the longest to execute. Is there a way to index a GROUP BY function?

Comment: Is this something I could do as a stored procedure?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the query plan (EXPLAIN).

Comment: How much time does it actually take to execute the query? How big is the table (number of rows) and how many rows are returned in the result? And - it is probably related - what are the specs of the server (RAM) and settings of Postgres (`shared_buffers` and `work_mem`)?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a simple approach:

Execute inside psql, enable *\timing* and run your query. Also check query execution plan:

```
explain select <your query>;
```

Then run vacuum for your table:

```
vacuum (full, analyze, verbose) employee_employee;
```

And check if query execution plan was improved, you'll see what's the costly stage:

```
explain select <your query>;
```

Considering that your query is a simple query, there's no much to do beyond that inside the database.
**Optionally** evaluate if a materialized view fits your need.

Comment: Did you applied the suggestions? Some improvement?